# singleton pattern asp.net webproject with .asmx webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, singleton, asmx

I am implementing a connection pooling in .net project
I have a .asmx webservice in my asp.net project which is used to obtain connectionID.
I added a class TicketManager.cs which i made singleton using below

```
    private static readonly TicketManager TicketManagerInstance=new TicketManager();
    public static TicketManager GetTicketManagerInstance()
    {
        return TicketManagerInstance;
    }
```

.Using my webservice i do operations to obtain ticket.But when I deployed this project in IIS i get different results.I have a webmethod to list out current connections in USE.When i try to get this.I see different results on different requests .I suspect my singleton class might be instantiated multiple times.Can you suggest something?
How should i make it work in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: Your static instance will be used for all requests. Is that what you intended? Also, why would that be thread-safe?

Comment: And, thread-safe, why? By default, the world is not thread-safe.

Comment: I am implementing pooling with this.This class is used to give user a ticket which is used to access somelinks in our website.We have a limit on this (Example if it is 80 81st user wont be able to access.If it is not thread safe if 80th and 81st user tries to fetch ticket at sametime we might encounter issues).So i need it to be threadsafe.

Comment: But you have done nothing to endure safety. I see a problem with app pool restart. You would have two copies of your singleton at that time.

Comment: Finally I am using app pool with only 1 worker process and saving the tickets in Database.Thanks for help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I am using app pool with only 1 worker process and saving the tickets in Database